# send arguments to drupal view with ajax

Tags: ajax, drupal, view

I have an ajax view block with some filters. I would like to update the filters of the view from outside with javascript.

How can I send arguments to a view from outside of the block without refreshing the page?

Comment: Are you using URL flags like "http://domain.com/page.php?id=1&comment=2" and you want to use AJAX to update those variables? Are you using any javascript framework like jQuery, YUI, or Dojo?

Comment: I'm working on this site: http://d6d7.joergpfeiffer.de
I would like to change the dropdown "Has taxonomy term " above the map with a javascript frunction. A javascript function I call from outside the map block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the javascript I ended up using to load the views block with ajax and pass in the contextual filter from the `href` value of a list of links I created on page. Hope this helps someone!

```
function getInfo(args) {

  $.ajax({
    url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      view_name: 'agent_lookup',
      view_display_id: 'agent_lookup_block', //your display id
      view_args: args,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response[1] !== undefined) {
        var viewHtml = response[1].data;
        $('#ajax-target').html(viewHtml);
        //Drupal.attachBehaviors(); //check if you need this.
      }

    },
        error: function(data) {
         alert('An error occured!');
        }
  });
}



$('.ajax_button').once().click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var the_id = $(this).attr('href');
    noSlashes = the_id.replace(/\//g,'');
    getInfo(noSlashes);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Auto Submit sub-module from [Views Hacks](http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) might prove super useful here. I use that a lot. You could always set it up, then trigger from outside even with just causing clicks via JS.